# Can I resubmit a question that was closed by moderators?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked a question a few weeks back that was closed for being too broad. I have restructured the question to make it more specific. Can I resubmit it or would it be closed again for being a duplicate?

Comment: A good idea would be to join the chatroom here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor you can talk to people there about your question and what needs doing to fix it. Most of the people in the room will be able to start the re-opening process once it is ready as well.

Answer (score 6):

### Use the Edit, Luke!

You are correct that reposting an "on hold" question will get it closed as a duplicate.  You can *edit* your existing question to improve it though, and that will put it in a queue of questions to be reviewed and (hopefully, if the new question is good enough) reopened.

More details:

- Read the comments about why your question was put "on hold". We use the term "on hold" specifically because they can be reopened if fixed.
- Make edits to the question to address the concerns of the editors.
- Then wait a bit... after a question is edited, it goes in the review queue. It took five editors to put your question on hold... it takes five editors to agree to reopen it. It does happen.
- While waiting, you can use Meta or chat to talk to folks to better understand the issues with your question.

Comment: how often does that happen though? i tried editing it before but nothing was done. should i just keeping editing it?

Comment: @Shardmartin -- keep editing it

Comment: Once a question has moved from "on hold" to "closed", an edit doesn't automatically put it into the reopen queue.  But it's perfectly fine to ask on meta (or in chat) if it can be reopened.  Once *somebody* casts a reopen vote, it'll go into the review queue.

Comment: @Shardmartin Reopening happens with great regularity when a questioner reads the comments and makes the edits requested! :-) I review the reopen queues at least once a day, and I know others do as well.

Answer (score 4):

Shalvenay explained what to do: edit the old closed question, and then click on the `reopen` button which is among the grey items just below the tags, after the body.

You can also discuss the question here on meta: since it already has a post you can refer to it doesn’t make sense to use the **sandbox** in this case, but can post a meta discussion like you did here.

You can also use the [chat] room, but that depends on who’s around when you wander in.  Point is, you don’t have to guess at it, but have ways to **discuss** the broadness issues and specific ways of reworking.